# How to separate Date & Time from this in PHP

Tags: php

> Sat Feb 3 19:34:10 2018

This is not timestamp.

I want get separate date and time from this data. How to do it in PHP.

Comment: Is that format fixed? No weird or unexpected variants? An `explode(' ',$date)` would give you an array with: day_of_week, month, day_of_month, time and year.

Comment: can you edit your answer and post the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
$myvalue = 'Sat Feb 3 19:34:10 2018';
$datetime = new DateTime($myvalue);
$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

This code will help you.

Answer (score -2):

Quick and dirty way to get the date if you know the format is just run

```
explode(' ', 'Sat Feb 3 19:34:10 2018')[3]
```

Comment: this one is super dirty and can break easily. I would not recommend to use it, since you can just use one of the build-in PHP functions for datetime.